# How to replace several words using python if order may change?

Tags: python, replace, translate

I want to create a little homemade translation tool where only a specific list of sentences is translated.
I have learnt to use the replace() method but my main problem is that I am translating from English to Spanish so two problems appear:

-the order reverses many times

-sometimes a group of words is translated as just one, and also sometimes a single word has to be translated as two or more

I know how to translate word by word but that is not enough for this problem. 
In this particular case I guess I have to translate whole chuncks of words.

How could I do that?

I know how to translate word by word.

I am able to define two lists, in the first one I put the original english words to be translated, and in the other one the corresponding spanish words.

Then I get the input text, split it and using two for loops I check if any of the words are present. In case they are I use replace to change them for the Spanish version.

After that I use the join method adding a space between words to get the final result.

```
a = (["Is", "this", "the", "most","violent","show"])

b = (["Es", "este", "el", "más", "violento", "show"])

text = "Is this the most violent show?"

text2 = text.split()

for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range ((text2.__len__())):
        if a[i] == text2[j]:
           text2[j] = b[i]
print ("Final text is: ", " ".join(text2))
```

The output is:

Final text is:  Es este el más violento show?

The result is on the wrong order since "más violento show" sounds weird in Spanish, it should be instead "show más violento".

What I want to learn is to put in the array a chuncks of words like this:

```
a = (["most violent show"])
b= (["show más violento"])
```

But in that case I can't use the split tool and I am a bit lost on how to do this.

Comment: I see some typos, unfortunately I can't find the edit button. I am so sorry about that.

Comment: How to edit: refer to the image [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789) or click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57691804/edit)

Comment: So you want to be able to translate groups of words seen in an input sentence?

Comment: I think that your question already has an answer right [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791711/translate-a-phrase-using-dictionary-python)

Comment: Hi folks, thank you so much to everyone. the solution from Joseph is simple enogh for me to understand and it works. But there is a problem, and it is the numbers, if I have a sentence like this "we will meet on August 28, 2019" . The problem are the numbers, since they are variable I may need to tell the programm where to put them and tell him if you find a number output it exactly as it is in the input. I have to think about this before closing the thread.

Answer (score 2):

What about a more simple solution using replace and mapping:

```
t = {'aa': 'dd', 'bbb': 'eee', 'c c c': 'f f f'}
v = 'dd eee zz f f f'
output = v
for a, b in t.iteritems():
    output = output.replace(a, b)
print(output)
# 'aa bbb zz c c c'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a fairly complicated problem (if you allow it to be)! As of writing, some other answers are perfectly fine for this particular example, so if they work, please mark one of those as the accepted answer.

First off, you should use [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) for this. They are a "dictionary" where you look something up (the key) and get a definition (the value).

The difficult part is being able to match parts of the input phrase to-be-translated in order to get a translated output. Our general algorithm: go through every single one of the English key words/phrases and then translate them to Spanish.

There are a few problems:

1. You will be translating as-you-go, meaning if your translation contains words that could be *both* English and Spanish, you can run into nonsense translations.
2. English key words might be character subsets of other key terms, e.g.: `"most" -> "más", "most violent show" -> "show más violento"`.
3. You need to match case sensitivity.

I won't bother with 3 as it's not really in scope of the question and will take too long. Solving 2 is easiest: when reading the keys of the dictionary, order by length of the input key. Solving 1 is much harder: you need to know which terms have already been translated when looking at the "translation in progress."

So a complex but thorough solution for this is outlined below:

```py
translation_dict = {
    "is": "es",
    "this": "este",
    "the": "el",
    "most violent show": "show más violento",
}

input_phrase = "Is this the most violent show?"
translations = list()

# Force the translation to be lower-case.

input_phrase = input_phrase.lower()

for key in sorted(translation_dict.keys(), key=lambda phrase: -len(phrase)):
    spanish_translation = translation_dict[key]

    # Code will assume all keys are lower-case.

    if key in input_phrase:
        input_phrase = input_phrase.replace(key, "{{{}}}".format(len(translations)))
        translations.append(spanish_translation)

print(input_phrase.format(*translations))
```

---

There are yet more complex solutions if you know the max word size for a translation (i.e.: iterating `n`-grams where `n <= m`, and `m` is the largest group of words you expect to translate). You would iterate the `n`-gram for largest `m` first, attempting to search your translation dictionary, and decrementing `n` by 1 until you go through individual words to iterate.

For example, with `m = 3` with input: `"This is a test string."`, you would get the following English phrases that you would attempt to translate.

```
"This is a"
"is a test"
"a test string"
"this is"
"is a"
"a test"
"test string"
"this"
"is"
"a"
"test"
"string"
```

This can have a performance benefit with a huge translation dictionary. I would show it but this answer is complex enough as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you are looking for with the string `replace` method:

```
a = ("Is", "this", "the", "most violent show")

b = ("Es", "este", "el", "show más violento")

text = "Is this the most violent show?"
for val, elem in enumerate(a):
    text = text.replace(elem, b[val])

print(text)

>>> 'Es este el show más violento?'
```

Also note you have a list in a tuple which is redundant.

---

Note Caspar Wylie's solution is a neater method using dicts instead

Comment: Actually, the list is not in a tuple as it would need a trailing comma like `([],)` to tell it apart from a general grouping of expressions. Still, the brackets aren't needed.